# I can pass a variable from a JSP scriptlet to JSTL but not from JSTL to a JSP scriptlet without an error

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, scope, scriptlet

The following code causes an error:

```
 <c:set var="test" value="test1"/>
 <%
   String resp = "abc";
   resp = resp + test;
   pageContext.setAttribute("resp", resp);
 %>
 <c:out value="${resp}"/>
```

The error says

```
"error a line 4: unknown symbol 'test'".
```

How do I pass `test` from the JSTL code to the JSP scriptlet?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Scripts are raw java embedded in the page code, and if you declare variables in your scripts, then they become local variables embedded in the page.

In contrast, JSTL works entirely with scoped attributes, either at `page`, `request` or `session` scope. You need to rework your scriptlet to fish `test` out as an attribute:

```
<c:set var="test" value="test1"/>
<%
  String resp = "abc";
  String test = pageContext.getAttribute("test");
  resp = resp + test;
  pageContext.setAttribute("resp", resp);
%>
<c:out value="${resp}"/>
```

If you look at the docs for `<c:set>`, you'll see you can specify `scope` as  `page`, `request` or `session`, and it defaults to `page`.

Better yet, don't use scriptlets at all: they make the baby jesus cry.

Comment: JSTL makes me cry, or at least cringe when I have to read much of the fugly stuff.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 15):

@skaffman nailed it down. They live each in its own context. However, I wouldn't consider using scriptlets as *the* solution. You'd like to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) them. If all you want is to concatenate strings in EL and you discovered that the `+` operator fails for strings in EL (which is correct), then just do:

```
<c:out value="abc${test}" />
```

Or if `abc` is to obtained from another scoped variable named `${resp}`, then do:

```
<c:out value="${resp}${test}" />
```