# how to add comma to string in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I want to add comma to string which is retrieved from database .

in below code i am getting employee from database whose job is teacher

here is my code

```
<td>
    <% 
       sql2 = "SELECT empname FROM users WHERE job = ? ";
       ps2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
       ps2.setString(1, jobname);
       rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

         while (rs2.next()){ 
              String emp= rs2.getString("empname");
     %>                        
      <%=emp%> 

    <% } %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create on e [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `empname`

```
ArrayList<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs2.next())
{ 
   String emp= rs2.getString("empname");
   empList.add(emp);                  
}
```

Then you can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`isLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast%28%29)

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="empName" varStatus="loop">
   <c:out value="${empName}" />
   <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

You can use [isLast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast%28%29) method of `ResultSet` but,
I would recommend you not to use scriptlets in JSP
See [how to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

For working with JSTL you just need to put [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`
and in JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

**Update answer to comment**

> it does not printing result.

Scripts are raw java embedded in the page code, and if you declare variables in your scripts, then they become local variables embedded in the page.

In contrast, JSTL works entirely with scoped attributes, either at page, request or session scope.
So, for using ArrayList `empList` created in Scriptlets you need to modify the code. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570239/1031945)

```
<%
 ArrayList<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();
 while (rs2.next())
 { 
   String emp= rs2.getString("empname");
   empList.add(emp);                  
 }
 pageContext.setAttribute("empList", empList);//pageContext is implicit object available
%>
```

then above mentioned JSTL code will work fine.

**Related links**

- [can I pass a variable from a JSP scriptlet to JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3570191/1031945)
- [Implicit Objects in JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html)

Comment: it does not printing result.

Comment: @Sumit : Sorry. I forgot to tell you about JSTL needs jar. See my updated answer. See my updated post. It is working. I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rs2.isLast()` to check if the current `ResultSet` is last record and do not add `,` in that case. This, however is costly because the JDBC driver will fetch ahead one row in order to determine whether the current row is the last row in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

This would be enough..

```
<% 
   sql2 = "SELECT empname FROM users WHERE job = ? ";
   ps2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
   ps2.setString(1, jobname);
   rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
   boolean b = rs2.last();
    int numberOfRecords = 0;
   if(b){
   numberOfRecords = rs.getRow();
   System.out.println(numberOfRecords);
     }
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 while (rs.next()){ 
      if(numberOfRecords>1)
      {
      String emp= rs.getString("bank")+",";

      }
      else
      {

      String emp=rs.getString("bank");

      }
      numberOfRecords--;
 %>                        
  <%=emp%> 

<% } %>
```