# scripting elements in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, el, scopes

I am new to jsp.  I am writing one "declaration" and one "scriptlet" in a jsp page.

But the variables i created in declaration and in "scriptlet" does not store in any one of the

scope. ie page scope,request scope,application scope.why.

Here is my following jsp file named as "success.jsp",

```
     <%! int x=20; %>//x is not created in any scope.
    <% int y=30; %>// y is not created in any scope.

   <script>

  var p="${x}";//here,variable p does not get any value.
  var q="${y}";//here,variable does not get any value.

  </script>
```

why the variables "x" and "y" does not created in any one of the scope.And how to get the values stored in "x" and "y" variables.

Comment: ${x} is for EL not Scriptlets. Scriptlets uses <%=x%>

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to start understanding jsps is that they are secretly being interpreted into java classes. But more specifically: They are being put into a function that is writing out the html line by line, after evaluating each line. Hence why you can have the <% %> tags. Now, because of that, the <% %> tags are actually lines that are evaluated but not written to the html. The evaluations are stored in the scope of the *resulting java method*. So what ends up happening looks something like:

```
public void SendHtmlPage() {
  int x=20; 
  int y=30; 

  Print("<script>");

  Print("var p=\"${x}\"\;"); //This gets evaluated to getSession.getAttribute("x")
                             //Since there is no x in the session, it returns null
  Print("var q=\"${y}\"\;"); //Same here

  Print("</script>);
}
```

So. That is why x and y aren't known inside your scriptlet. However, there are ways to save the method scoped variables to session scope. Check this out: [I can pass a variable from a JSP scriptlet to JSTL but not from JSTL to a JSP scriptlet without an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570191/i-can-pass-a-variable-from-a-jsp-scriptlet-to-jstl-but-not-from-jstl-to-a-jsp-sc)

Good luck and happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
var p = <%=x%>;
var q = <%=y%>;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the variables created by the jsp-scriplet code `<%! int x=20; %>` are not available in any scope, as they are directly declared inside the compiled jps page (any jsp page internally compiled to a servlet class).
For using the variable *x* in the rest of the jsp page you have two different options:

1. Use jsp-scriplet expressions `<%= x %>` and in this case the code inside your javascipt fragment would be:

   var p = "<%= x%>";
   var q = "<%= y%>";
2. Manually save the variables *x, y* inside the *pageContext* scope, in this way they become available from the EL:

   <%
   int x=20;
   int y=30;
   **pageContext.setAttribute("x", x);**
   **pageContext.setAttribute("y", y);**
   %>

As a note, be aware that `<%! int x = 20; %>` is different from `<% int x=20; %>`.