# JSP String To Java Class

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp page. Page have a requested field as string.

```
<% String token = ""+request.getParameter(); %>
```

In this jsp page also has a test class.

```
 <%!
      public static String usetoken()
          {
              String testtoken = ""+token;
          }

 %>
```

This usetoken class can not solve the token string. How can I solve that ? I need to call a string inside a class which inside a jsp page.

Thanks,

Comment: I hope this is usefull for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183108/how-to-print-a-java-string-in-a-jsp-file

Comment: @ottis79 no it is not. Please read carrefully. I can use like that. But I can not insert token string to class.

Comment: `token` is a local variable, not existing in definition context (i.e. inside `<%! ... %>` block)

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I know that but inside <%! ... %> request is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as you may know, a jsp will be compiled to a servlet. All scriptlet code will be "inserted" into service() method and all declarations will be inserted to servlet class. So, for your situation, we'll have something like this(simplified):

```
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static String useToken() {
        String testtoken = ""+ token;
        return testtoken;
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = ""+ request.getParameter();
    }
}
```

As you see, userToken() method can't know about 'token' local variable inside service() method.

Also, you can't access HttpServletRequest in your jsp declaration, because it's a parameter of service() method.

**BUT**

You can use JSTL for something like this. You can declare variable:

```
<c:set var="token" value="${requestScope.token}"/>
```

And access it anywhere in your jsp using expression language(EL):

```
${token}
```

---

If you don't know, writing scriptlets inside your jsp [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/6761717). You need to do business logic somewhere outside and provide view as jsp. So use JSTL, your custom tags and EL.