# Can't compare two Strings in a JSP file

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this Jsp file

```
<SELECT name="brandsFrom" onchange="as()">
    <c:forEach items="${brandsSelectedList}" var="brands">
        <c:if test="${brands.name == nam}">
        <option value="${brands.id}">${brands.id}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</SELECT>
```

i have declared nam above this code like

```
<%!
String nam;
%>
<%
nam=request.getParameter("name"); 
out.println("value in the string ="+nam+"+");
%>
```

When i use

```
<c:if test="${brands.name == nam}">
```

the code doesn't rum whereas when i use something like this

```
<c:if test="${brands.name == 'Denim'}">
```

the code runs . Why am i not being able to use nam variable ??

Comment: The check looks correct to me. Are you sure that the values of the variables are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Did you get some output from `out.println("value in the string ="+nam+"+");`?

Comment: tried `<c:if test="${brands.name eq nam}">` ?

Comment: You don't need to use nam.  You can use <c:if test="${brands.name == param.name}">  If you insist on using nam, then you should learn the difference between scripting variables and scoped variables.

Comment: Thanks @rickz your solution worked but i still want to know why the earlier one didn't work . I tried reading about the scope of variables in a jsp file and wasn't able to figure out the reason why it wasn't working

Comment: Look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570191/i-can-pass-a-variable-from-a-jsp-scriptlet-to-jstl-but-not-from-jstl-to-a-jsp-scriptlet-without-an-error

Answer (score 0):

It could be because brands.name is coming from brandsSelectedList which would be being set in your ActionSerlvet overridden method whereas nam is a local variable defined in JSP. Variables defined in jsp might not be accesible in your expression langauge code.
I haven't tried but look at the corresponding generarted class file through a decompiler for JSP and see what's going on there